# Como fazer com que a aplicaçao aceda ha base de dados local(BLL & DAL)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Eu tenho esta ligação feita para aceder há base de dados local, que ao usar o executavel no computador onde criei a aplicaçao funciona e consegue aceder ha base de dados.
 public DAL()
        {
            _SqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\staff.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

```
    }
```

e o meu problema é que quando executo o programa noutro computador do qual nao tem instalado o visual studio ele abre mas nao encontra a base de dados que esta na mesma pasta que o excutavel.

[image: pasta que se envia com o executavel e a base de dados]

Comment: Tenta assim :  _SqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="+System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath+@"\staff.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

Comment: José Gomes obrigado pela ajuda mas nao funcionou com essa alteração agora nem acede ha base de dados no computador onde esta a ser criado

Comment: volta ao código anterior então e vai à base de dados buscar a ligação à mesma e põe aqui por favor

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\SOFIA\Desktop\ESTAGIO\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\bin\Debug\staff.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Comment: supostamente essa ligação está bem feita. escreve de novo porque o vs às vezes tem bugs

Comment: Uma das razoes que eu acho que nao funciona é porque o outro computador nao tem algum programa especifico para abrir a base de dados

Comment: se tiver o visual studio instalado consegue abrir a base de dados sem problema. Qual a versão do visual studio em que foi criado o projeto? E qual é a do pc em que estas a tentar executar?

Comment: A versao do visual studio é o 2017 e o objetivo é passar o programa a funcionar para outro computador que nao tem o visual studio, o problema é que no computador que eu quero passar que nao tem o visual studio nao consegue abrir a base de dados para demonstrar e inserir informaçoes numa datagrid view

Comment: ele normalmente funciona na mesma